# Pilha não funciona corretamente no Codeblocks

Tags: c

Esse código abaixo compila tanto no Codeblocks quanto no Visual Studio, só que a saída é diferente no Codeblocks. Pelo VS eu não excluo nada do código abaixo, é só rodar e pronto, agora no Codeblocks eu tirei essas duas bibliotecas:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
```

e adicionei essas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

mudei o `scanf_s` para `scanf`

e compilei, compila normalmente, só que a saída tá errada, isso no Codeblocks. No VS é tranquilo funciona normalmente.

Queria saber o que há de errado pelo Codeblocks, quero rodar com saída perfeita no Codeblocks.

```
// pilha.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"

#define TAM_PILHA 2
#define NUM_ENTRA 5

void empilha(int *pilha, int *topo, int valor)
{
if (*topo <= TAM_PILHA)
{
    pilha[*topo] = valor;
    (*topo)++;
}
else
{
    printf("Pilha Cheia\n");
}
}

int desempilha(int *pilha, int *topo)
{
if (*topo > 0)
{
    (*topo)--;
    return pilha[*topo];
}
else
{
    printf("Pilha Vazia\n");
}
}

int main()
{
int pilha_par[TAM_PILHA], pilha_impar[TAM_PILHA], topo_par = 0, topo_impar = 0;
int i = 0, num_do_usuario = 0;
for (i = 0; i < NUM_ENTRA; i++)
{
    printf("\nEntre com um numero: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num_do_usuario);

    if ((num_do_usuario % 2) == 0)
    {
        empilha(pilha_par, &topo_par, num_do_usuario);
    }
    else
    {
        empilha(pilha_impar, &topo_impar, num_do_usuario);
    }

}

printf("\n\nNumeros pares sao: ");
while (topo_par > 0)
{
    printf("%d ", desempilha(pilha_par, &topo_par));
}

printf("\n\nNumeros impares sao: ");
while (topo_impar > 0)
{
    printf("%d ", desempilha(pilha_impar, &topo_impar));
}

printf("\n\n");

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Errado:

[image: Erro ao empilhar/desempilhar]

Outro cenário de erro:

[image: Erro novamente]

Comment: E o que deu errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está fazendo o empilhamento errado.

Suas pilhas tem tamanho TAM_PILHA, logo a verificação na hora de empilhar deve ser:

```
if (*topo < TAM_PILHA)
```

ao invés de

```
if (*topo <= TAM_PILHA)
```

Eu copiei teu código, compilei e executei no Windows 10. Segue as entradas e saídas:
**Entradas**

> 10, 10, 15, 15, 15

**Saída**

> Numeros pares sao: 10 15
>
> Numeros impares sao: 15 15 15

Já em outro teste foi lido apenas 4 valores. Ou seja, o programa não mostrava resultados esperados e nem tinha o comportamento desejado. Novamente no Windows 10.

Por outro lado, no Ubuntu 16.04 as entradas e o resultado foram:

**Entradas**

> 10, 10, 15, 15, 15

**Saída**

> Numeros pares sao: 10 10
>
> Numeros impares sao: 15 15 15

O resultado, por mais que pareça correto, continua errado. Pois a TAM_PILHA vale 2, ou seja, a pilha deveria guardar somente 2 elementos.

Fazendo a alteração listadas lá em cima o programa executa como o esperado e produz os resultados corretos.

**Ps1: Usei os cabeçalhos stdlib.h e stdio.h.**
**Ps2: Compilei com GCC e executei no cmd windows. Em ambos os códigos(original e alterado).**
**Ps3: Compilei com G++ e executei no bash do Ubuntu.**

Comment: Olha eu fiz isso que vc disse e não surtiu de primeira o efeito esperado, pelo menos aqui no CB. Não está lendo o último vetor.

Comment: Como assim lendo o último vetor? Se você definiu a pilha com tamanho 2, então ela deve ser capaz de guardar 2 elementos. Se você está lendo 5 entradas, não vai caber todas as entradas nas 2 pilhas. Acabei de rodar seu código em um Ubuntu 16.04 e rodou certo. O único problema é que o teu código guarda na posição pilha[2]. Esta posição não existe na pilha, porém a linguagem C te permite fazer isso. Na verdade seu código precisa de apenas 1 alteração, no caso a primeira que eu citei.

Comment: me mande uma mensagem que mostro no team view

Comment: Poste alguns prints para ficar mais claro. Talvez estamos falando de problemas distintos.

Comment: tudo bem ja postei aí

Comment: De acordo com este print o funcionamento está OK. Tudo ocorreu como o esperado. A pilha par contém apenas números pares e a pilha ímpar contém apenas números ímpares. E por fim, não foi possível empilhar mais números na pilha ímpar, pois esta já estava cheia(2 elementos).

Comment: Não tem como isso está certo isso, o número 3 e 5 não estão sendo impressos, e olho outro cenário que postei aí.

Comment: Exatamente, eles não deveriam estar sendo impressos. Isso acontece pois a pilha tem o tamanho definido pela constante TAM_PILHA. Caso TAM_PILHA valha 2, então a pilha poderá empilhar no máximo 2 elementos. Caso valha 3, então a pilha poderá empilhar no máximo 3 elementos. No seu exemplo, provavelmente ela está valendo 2. Então ao tentar inserir um terceiro elemento haverá um erro de " pilha cheia". Ou seja, quando acontecer o processo de desempilhamento, este número não estará na pilha e consequentemente não será desempilhado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55436/discussion-between-thiago-ferreira-and-carlos-givisiez).